# Hitbox bug in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, collision-detection

I'm making a videogame in javascript (without canvas because it's an assignement and teacher forbid us to us canvas). I'm making the hitbox right now and i run into some bug. the one i wanna talk about is this one:

[image: Picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

When i load the page the character spawns in the air and fall due to a `gravity` function:

```
//* GRAVITY

let force = setInterval(gravity, 10);

let fall = true;

function gravity(){
    if(fall){
        // loop that multiplie the velocity by 1.05 until it's at 40
        if (gforce < 20) gforce = gforce * 1.05;

        // Apply gravity to character
        persoY = persoY + gforce;
        persoId.style.top = persoY + 'px';

        //! debugging
        console.log(gforce);
    }
}
```

Then when it touches the ground it stops falling because of my hitbox function:

```
let touch = true;

function coll(){
    if(touch){
        let persoY = persoId.offsetTop,
            persoX = persoId.offsetLeft,
            persoW = persoId.offsetWidth,
            persoH = persoId.offsetHeight,
            islandY = islandHitbox.offsetTop,
            islandX = islandHitbox.offsetLeft,
            islandW = islandHitbox.offsetWidth,
            islandH = islandHitbox.offsetHeight;
        if (persoX < islandX + islandW &&
            persoX + persoW > islandX &&
            persoY < islandY + islandH &&
            persoY + persoH > islandY) {
            fall = false;
        } else {
            fall = true;
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(coll);
}
coll();
```

Now the problem is that when the page load and the player fall there's a 50% chance he stop falling right when he touches the hitbox like in [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0oho.jpg) or another 50% chance that he clips a bit through the hitbox before he stops falling like in [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSk3a.jpg) And i really can't understand why pls help me thx u already.

Comment: are you using padding on the container?

Comment: @Mehrwarz nope there's no padding or margin just a 15px border to mark hitboxs visually

Comment: Your `gforce` variable represents acceleration-due-to-gravity, right? If so, then it should be a constant and you should use a different variable to represent an entity's velocity (or vertical speed) - if `gforce` is your vertical-speed then give it a different name because "G-force" means something completely different. Secondarily, do not use the `offset...` properties to represent displacement or translation, because the DOM is not a game engine.

Comment: instead of `border` try using `outline`

Comment: @Dai Yes the `gforce` variable is the vertical acceleration. This is my first time ever using javascript so idk what DOM is what else than `offset` should i use then?

Comment: @Dai Oh and it's not a const because it accelerate overtime

Comment: @yazukii Fixed gravity causes constant acceleration, constant acceleration causes velocity to increase over time. Gravity does not cause something to "accelerate-its-acceleration". You cannot build any kind of 2D or 3D game with gravity without [a basic understanding of mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion) (see the heading "Constant translational acceleration in a straight line" for the "SUVAT" equations, which are what you need to implement a 2D platformer game engine).

Comment: Why is your `gravity` function being invoked via `setInterval` but your `coll` function is invokved via `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: @Dai thanks you i will look into it to have a better understanding of it! And one is invoked with `setInterval` and another one with `requestAnimationFrame` because when i was doing the gravity i discovered `setInterval` and when i was doing the hitbox i discovered `requestAnimationFrame`. As i said its my very first time using js